# Simple ECG waveform samples?

Tags: python, signal-processing, bioinformatics

I am looking for a sample of an ECG waveform for a simplified demo application for a intro to programming class for biomedical technology students. They will be displaying the waveform on screen to build a super simple ECG chart recorder.

Yes, I'm aware of the MIT-BIH Normal Sinus Rhythm Database, but that's way too complicated for my purposes. I want students to focus on the programming aspect. We are using Python with a simple graphics library from cs1graphics.org .

I could do it myself with a patient simulator and a digitizing scope, but I'm hoping someone on this forum has something handy. Even just one cycle of the sinus rhythm would be enough, since I can just loop it.

Thanks in advance
 --Louis

Answer (score 1):

Hope, this is of some help to you:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinus_rhythm#/media/File:SinusRhythmLabels.svg

Comment: Hi frederick99, not what I had in mind but it's quite a good illustration. I'm looking for a sequence of digitized samples suitable for DSP. Thanks

Comment: i found this - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387878/simulator-of-realistic-ecg-signal-from-rr-data-for-matlab-or-python) hope this one helps.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! I wouldn't have found it on my own. Thanks!